# How can I add a GitHub Packages resolver to an Ammonite script?

Tags: scala, github, github-package-registry, ammonite

Does anyone know how I can add a GitHub Packages resolver to an Ammonite script?

I'm quite used to using GitHub Packages with sbt, but we use the `sbt-github-packages` plugin, which makes it very easy to add a GitHub Packages resolver to a build.sbt file. E.g., in build.sbt, I merely include:

```
resolvers += Resolver.githubPackages("myCompany")
```

Since I can't use the `sbt-github-packages` plugin with Ammonite, I'm sure that the answer is significantly more complicated with Ammonite.

With the `sbt-github-packages` plugin, for authentication, I have my GitHub token in an environment variable called GITHUB_TOKEN, and an Ammonite solution would also have to perform the proper authentication.